# Exact order of job execution for Rails delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm using collectiveidea's version of delayed_job: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Can anyone point me to the actual criteria used when a worker goes to pick the next job to work on?  I'm assuming it's something like "SELECT id FROM delayed_jobs WHERE run_at > NOW() ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1" (picks by priority first, run_at time second), but I haven't been able to find exactly what's considered.  I've done some poking about in the code on GitHub, but haven't found the actual query for the next job.  Curious on a couple things, including whether 'created_at', 'attempts' or 'failed_at' factor into prioritization at all.  (and I realize I'm unlikely to find actual SQL, just an easy way to represent what I assume the query does).

Secondarily, any good sources of actual documentation for this gem?  For something that's used so commonly in Rails, the documentation I've seen is pretty darn sparse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of digging through the source showed this in backend/active_record.rb:

```
    scope :ready_to_run, lambda {|worker_name, max_run_time|
      where(['(run_at <= ? AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < ?) OR locked_by = ?) AND failed_at IS NULL', db_time_now, db_time_now - max_run_time, worker_name])
    }
    scope :by_priority, order('priority ASC, run_at ASC')

    # Find a few candidate jobs to run (in case some immediately get locked by others).
    def self.find_available(worker_name, limit = 5, max_run_time = Worker.max_run_time)
      scope = self.ready_to_run(worker_name, max_run_time)
      scope = scope.scoped(:conditions => ['priority >= ?', Worker.min_priority]) if Worker.min_priority
      scope = scope.scoped(:conditions => ['priority <= ?', Worker.max_priority]) if Worker.max_priority

      ::ActiveRecord::Base.silence do
        scope.by_priority.all(:limit => limit)
      end
    end
```

Also, this bit in backend/base.rb is of interest:

```
    def reserve(worker, max_run_time = Worker.max_run_time)
      # We get up to 5 jobs from the db. In case we cannot get exclusive access to a job we try the next.
      # this leads to a more even distribution of jobs across the worker processes
      find_available(worker.name, 5, max_run_time).detect do |job|
        job.lock_exclusively!(max_run_time, worker.name)
      end
    end
```

`reserve` is called by a worker to choose the next job.

Comment: Thanks, very useful.  Interesting that it uses the 'failed_at' column to determine not to try again, rather than attempts < max_attempts.  That does mean that increasing number of attempts in config won't make "failed" jobs attempt to run again.

Comment: Of course, that does have the useful effect that you can force a 'failed' job to run again by simply clearing the failed_at field rather than increasing the max attempts config or clearing/reducing the recorded attempts for that job.

Comment: There might be more to it. At a guess, `failed_at` may not be set until the job is attempted the maximum number of times. delayed_job is supposed to retry jobs if configured that way.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about that, Alex.  failed_at remains NULL until the max number of attempts is reached.  I had a number of jobs that had been attempted and 25 times (default max) because of a configuration issue.  Simply setting failed_at=NULL caused them to be attempted a 26th time without needing to increase the configured max number of tries.

Comment: fwiw, ActiveRecord support has been factored out of Delayed::Job and can now be found in https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record -- that explains why I couldn't find the definition for `find_available` :).

Answer (score 1):

```
delayed_job/lib/delayed/backend/active_record.rb
```

`self.find_available` calls `ready_to_run`
then scopes it based on the current workers min/max priority
then orders it by `priority ASC, run_at ASC`

the `scope :ready_to_run` calls

```
where(['(run_at <= ? AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < ?) OR locked_by = ?) AND failed_at IS NULL', db_time_now, db_time_now - max_run_time, worker_name])
```

so it generates something like

```
SELECT * FROM jobs where run at <= ? AND locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < ?) OR locked_by = ?) AND failed_at IS NULL AND priority >= ? AND priority <= ? ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC
```